# Group table rows using intermediate multicolumn headers

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I have a data frame which I am putting through Hmisc:latex() to generate a formatted table with pdflatex. What I'd like to do is to group the table rows into sections based on a data column, and insert multicolumn rows (spanning all columns) containing headers for these sections.

E.g. if I have:

```
> x = data.frame(A=rep(c('a', 'b'), each=2), X=1:4, Y=5:8)
> x
  A X Y
1 a 1 5
2 a 2 6
3 b 3 7
4 b 4 8
```

I'd like to have x formatted as:

```
-----------
   X      Y
-----------
a
-----------
   1      5
   2      6
b
-----------
   3      7
   4      8
-----------
```

I know I can do it with *rgroup*, *n.rgroup* in Hmisc:latex(), but the problem is that it requires using row names in x, so the row group headers only span the first table column, which contains row names. My 'a' and 'b' group headers are in reality long text lines which would require the whole table width, and I have quite a few columns instead of just X and Y, hence I have no space (nor need) for row names.

As one idea I noticed in the *tables* package vignette (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) the use of *doEnd*, *doFooter*, etc, options that can be passed to the latex() call, so that the table does not get closed, and I can manually cat(\multicolumn{..}{l}{My row group header ...}, and then follow up with another latex() call, this time with *doEnd=TRUE*. The problem here is that it seems to work with an object produced by tables:tabular(), but not with a straight data frame like x above. I do not know if it is possible to do a straight cast of a data frame to tabular object (the formula approach in tables seems complex to me).

I would appreciate any ideas on how to handle this problem.

Best regards,

Aleksey

Comment: Why don't you simply use \multicolumn{}{×}{×} in a tabular environment?